# JS returning wrong time on startup on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I experienced a little problem on Firefox the other day. I am writing code to measure performance of the web site that I'm working on.

For this test all I do is call new Date().toLocaleString() every 10 milliseconds and log the times it returns. The first time returned always seems to be a few milliseconds (or even seconds) AFTER the current time. Then the next measurements are always correct, it's only the first measurement that returns "future" time, then it seems to get itself together.

This only happens on starting up the browser. When I refresh the browser I don't see this happening.
I ran this on Chrome as well but there it seems to work.

Here are some times from the log I'm getting:

28/07/2017, 16:18:34
28/07/2017, 16:18:20
28/07/2017, 16:18:21
28/07/2017, 16:18:22
28/07/2017, 16:18:23
28/07/2017, 16:18:24
28/07/2017, 16:18:25
..etc

As you can see the first time is totally off, it's 14 seconds later than the next measurement. From the second one however, it all works fine.

I know it's not a major issue and it's easy enough to work around it but I was wondering if anyone else has seen this happening before and what could be the cause for this.

Comment: How do you know what the real current time is when the code runs?

Comment: I assume the current time is wrong on first measurement because it shows later time compared to the following one. From the second one however, it all increases normally. I added some logs to the question to show what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, that’s pretty weird. Can you show the code for the test you’re using? Does `performance.now()` give the expected results?